# How do I migrate from depricated Xml class in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I am currently using the following code to parse html from a trouble ticketing website maintained by my agency. Xml class has made it very easy to do so, but has long been deprecated and I'm afraid my script will soon break. I am not having any luck using the newer XmlService class. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www2.amss.nws.noaa.gov/amsstt.nsf/wSingleCatOpenAll?OpenForm').getContentText();      
var doc = Xml.parse(html, true);  
var table = doc.html.body.form.table[1];  
var trs = table.tr;
for (var r = 1; r < trs.length; r++) {    
  var tds = trs[r].td;
  var ticketId = tds[0].font.a.href;
  var ticketNo = tds[2].font.Text;
} ...etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this statement is the concern:

```
var doc = Xml.parse(html, true);
```

You have a `true` parameter, but the current documentation doesn't have a second parameter.

Have you tried:

```
var doc = XmlService.parse(html);
```

[Documentation - xmlService Parse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#parse(String))

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
Xml.parse(html,true)
```

implicitly adds an `<html>` tag and a `<body>` tag

With

```
XmlService.parse(html)
```

you won't have those tags in your result